# Does a certain cable arrangement that reduces the generated magnetic field improve shielding properties as well?

Tags: electromagnetism, cables, three-phase, shielding, magnetic-flux

If I arrange a three phase cable via phase-split into an arrangement that reduces the generated magentic field, does this affect shielding properties as well?

To reduce the generated magnetic field of an AC loaded three phase (T,S,R) cable, each phase can be split into two sub-conductors and can be arrangend as in Fig. 1. (0) indicates the neutral conductor.

According to Biot-Savart this arrangement reduces the generated magnetic field if the cable is loaded with an AC current.

**Question:**

Does this arrangement improve the shielding properties in the *same manner* as if an external time varying magnetic field is applied, the cable is not loaded and we would measure the induced voltage/current?

If yes, what is the theoretical background that interconnects: **1.** shielding against external sources and **2.** reduced generated magnetic fields of a cable?

[image]

Comment: Purely out of curiosity: what use case demands that your 3-phase power conductor gets well-shielded against external magnetic fields?

Comment: There might be none in case of a 3 phase power conductors. But, phase-splitting and certain cable arrangements are applyable on other use cases and are not limited to 3-phase power conductors. If there is an theoretical interconnection, it might be easier to measure the reduce magnetic field outside the cable than measuring the induced voltage inducted by an varying external magnetic field. In that way, I could calculate the interefernce currents more easily by measuring the corresponding generated magnetic fields of each single loaded cable arrangement.

Comment: ah, that's clever!

Answer (score 1):

> Does a certain cable arrangement that reduces the generated magnetic field, improves shielding properties as well?

Yes.

By *reciprocity*, if greater the magnetic field created by a current within a cable, the greater the effect of a changing external magnetic field upon the induced voltage within the cable. Likewise, the less the magnetic field created by a current within a cable, the less the effect of a changing external magnetic field upon the induced voltage within the cable.

If one thinks of the external magnetic field as being associated with an external wire, the situation can be thought of as a case of mutual inductance. Mutual inductance has the property of *reciprocity*. That is, if we have coils A and B, then the voltage induced in B by a change of current in A is equal to the voltage induced in A by a similar change in the current in B.

$$M = \frac{V_A}{\frac{dI_B}{dt}} = \frac{V_B}{\frac{dI_A}{dt}}$$

Comment: In other words: The change of the currents must be equal to ensure that a equal voltage is induced in either coils. If the current change is not equal, the induced voltage would at least differ in a certain factor? For instance, if I_B changes with 50Hz and I_A with 60 Hz?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, but I believe you are misinterpreting the Mutual inductance equation I posted. What it is saying is the voltage induced in one wire by a change in current in another wire will _always_  be the same as the voltage that would be induced in the second wire by a similar change in current in the first wire. That is, the mutual inductance is the same whether you calculate from wire A to B or from wire B to A.

Comment: I try to rephrase. If I want to ensure that the induced voltage V_A in Coil A by Coil B is the same as the induced voltage V_B in coil B by coil A , the change in current for either coils must be the same? If the change in current of A differs from B consequently the induced voltage differs.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: As previous, might be a stupid question. The relation given in your anwser is not limited by any coil parameters. If coil A has ten windings less or would larger in diameter than B, the induced voltage would still be determined by the current change?